# how to write for loop and if clause in angular js view template

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular js & working on it ,to develop a shopping cart(E-com) Website.I'm having a little problem with my code.I have to increment a variable in a for loop in a view page, even i have to write an if clause to display the button, is it possible to write a for loop & if clause in a view file? Please suggest some better tutorials to learn the Angularjs thoroughly.

Here is my code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr class="well">
        <td class="tdRight" colspan="4" >
            <a href="index.htm#/store" title="go to shopping cart" ng-disabled="cart.getTotalCount() < 1">
                <i class="icon-shopping-cart" />
                <b>{{cart.getTotalCount()}}</b> items, <b>{{cart.getTotalPrice() | currency}}</b>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in store.products | orderBy:'name' | filter:search" >

       <td class="tdCenter"><img ng-src="img/products/{{product.sku}}.jpg" alt="{{product.name}}" /></td>
        <td>
            <a href="#/products/{{product.sku}}"><b>{{product.name}}</b></a><br />
            {{product.description}}
        </td>
        <td class="tdRight">
            {{product.price | currency}}
        </td>
        <td class="tdCenter">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-hide="cart.getTotalCount() > 0" ng-click="cart.addItem(product.sku, product.name, product.price, 1)">+</button>

<span ng-int="counter=0;"></span>

<span ng-repeat="item in cart.items">

<span>{{ counter}}</span> // I want to increment the counter here, if counter will increment to 1 then have to display the button

<div>
    <span ng-if="item.name!=product.name">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-show="item.name!=product.name" ng-click="cart.addItem(product.sku, product.name, product.price, 1)">+</button>
    </span>
</div>


    <div ng-show="item.name==product.name">

<button class="btn btn-success"  type="button" ng-click="cart.addItem(product.sku, product.name, product.price, 1)">+</button>

<input class="span3 text-center" ng-change="cart.addItem(product.sku, product.name, product.price, this.value)" type='tel' ng-show="item.name==product.name" ng-model='item.quantity'>

<button class="btn btn-incerse" type="button" ng-click="cart.addItem(product.sku, product.name, product.price, -1)">-</button>
    </div>
</span>



        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="well">
        <td class="tdRight" colspan="4">
            <a href="index.htm#/store" title="go to shopping cart" ng-disabled="cart.getTotalCount() < 1">
                <i class="icon-shopping-cart" />
                <b>{{cart.getTotalCount()}}</b> items, <b>{{cart.getTotalPrice() | currency}}</b>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<button ng-if="$index >= 1">` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to code JS directly in HTML. 
Make another file for your script and include it to your HTML by puting this in the HTML-head:

```
 <script src="filename.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

For me it seems, as you're misinterpreting HTML as a procedural script, it's not. You don't want to increment at the procedural stage where the  is processed, due this never happens (HTML isnt a programming language).

Better think of HTML as a stencile that defines what kind of elements the page has, as well as their attributes. But HTML doesn't process anything.

But due you, and any other webdev, want to write stuff conditional, an HTML element can trigger functions and handover attributes (like a click).

So now you have to figure out, when exactly you need the increment.
Due it depends on the number of products in the card (if I got that right?) your incremental function has to be called whenever the number of products change, or whatever event you want to trigger the increment.

I'm not firm with angular syntax, so I'm using jQuery and comments:

```
// set the value of element with id "element_id" to ct
// this function directly alters the elements value, and returns true or  
// false, depending if the change has taken place.
function set_count( ct ){
    return $("#element_id").val( ct );
};

function count(){
    var ct;
    for ( whatever ) {
       ct++;
    };
    return ct;
}

// Now the trigger
<element onclick='set_count( count() )'>
```